# Duvidas - JSP - Servlets

Tags: mvc, jsp, servlet

Bom dia pessoal,
Estou tendo dificuldades para realizar o CRUD em um app de teste....

Fiz ele com o padrão (quase) MVC, o problema é que ao clicar no form de "Novo Produto" e preencher os campos ele não faz a inserção, somente me direciona a uma tela com o nome do Controller na url (ficando: http://localhost:8080/Teste/ProdutoController)

Esse é o cód do meu form:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>ADD novo Produto</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action='ProdutoController' name="formAddProduto">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="insert" />

            <table>

                <tr>
                    <td>Codigo de Barras</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="codBarras" />        
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Nome do produto</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Nome_Produto" />        
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Valor</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Valor_Produto" />        
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="submit" /></td>
                </tr>          
            </table>
        </form>
        <p><a href="ProdutoController?action=listProduto"> Todos os Produtos </a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Este é o trecho da Controller que pertence ao INSERT:

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String redirect="";
    String codBarras = request.getParameter("codBarras");        
    String action = request.getParameter("action");

    if(!((codBarras) == null) && action.equalsIgnoreCase("insert"))
    {
        int cb = Integer.parseInt("codBarras");

        Produto p = new Produto();
        p.setCodBarras(cb);
        p.setNmProduto(request.getParameter("Nome_Produto"));
        p.setValorProduto(Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("Valor_Produto")));

        dao.addProduto(p);

        redirect = ListaProduto;

        request.setAttribute("produtos", dao.getProdutos());  

        System.out.println("Produto adicionado com sucesso");
    }
```

Estou tendo esse mesmo problema com o formulário de Update.... ocorre a mesma coisa já os demais (listar Produto e Deletar Produto) estão normais.

Código do form de atualizar Produto:

```
<html>
<head>      
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Editar Produto</title>
</head>
<body>
    <% Produto p = new Produto(); %>
    <% ProdutoDAO dao = new ProdutoDAO(); %>

    <form method="POST" action='ProdutoController' name="formEditaProduto">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="edit" />
        <% String cb = request.getParameter("codBarras");
        if (!((cb) == null )){
            int cb2 = Integer.parseInt(cb);
            p = dao.getCodBarras(cb2);
         %>

        <table>
             <tr>
                <td>Codigo de Barras</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="codBarras" readonly="readonly" value="<%=p.getCodBarras()%>"> </td>        
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Nome do produto</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Nome_Produto" value="<%=p.getNmProduto()%>"/>        
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Valor</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Valor_Produto" value="<%=p.getValorProduto()%>"/>        
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Update" /></td>
            </tr>          
        </table>
                <% } else{ 
                        out.println("ID Not found");
                } %>

    </form>
</body>
```

E o código da Controller referente ao edit:

```
else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("edit")){

        String codBarras2 = request.getParameter("codBarras");

        int cb = Integer.parseInt(codBarras2);            
        Produto p = new Produto();
        p.setCodBarras(cb);
        p.setNmProduto(request.getParameter("Nome_Produto"));
        p.setValorProduto(Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("Valor_Produto")));

        dao.uptProduto(p);

        request.setAttribute("produto", p);
        redirect = ListaProduto;
        System.out.println("Record updated Successfully");
```

Answer (score 0):

As operações para insert e update são do tipo **POST** nos seus formulários. Sendo assim, o método no Servlet que deve recebe-las é o `doPost()` e não o `doGet()`. Basta trocar o método que deve funcionar.